# Export data from Dynamodb incrementally (say: of last 24 hrs)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I want to put a batch process to export upserts data from Dynamodb of last 24 hours only (every night). It's going to run in midnight and fine with some latency.

I know these options:
#1) scan the table(and having a updateDateTime attribute). But its going to be costly($$) as data grows.
#2) create a GSI on UpdateDate, and query this index using this partition key(hot partition issues, as well as extra cost of having a GSI and RCUs).

Tried this also https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-export-amazon-dynamodb-table-data-to-data-lake-amazon-s3/ - but it exports all the data till a datetime (and not last x hours)

Tried Athena and AWS Glue option, but exported data is not incremental

Please advise if there is a better way?

Note: I dont need all the events happening on DynamoDB (otherwise streams is a option). I want to export the end of the day snapshot(but incremental)

Comment: There is no other bulk export choice. You could potentially use DynamoDB streams or Kinesis to stream the changes to S3 as they happen and group by day that way.

Comment: @hunterhacker i changed the question and made it more generic. Can you recommend something which I am missing

Answer (score 0):

Incremental exports are a native DynamoDB feature as of September 2023.  See the AWS Blog [Introducing incremental export from Amazon DynamoDB to Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/introducing-incremental-export-from-amazon-dynamodb-to-amazon-s3/).

The feature extends the existing [DynamoDB to S3 export](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/S3DataExport.HowItWorks.html) functionality, which previously supported only a full table export.  With the new incremental export, you can specify a from and to export time:

```bash
aws dynamodb export-table-to-point-in-time \
  --table-arn arn:aws:dynamodb:REGION:ACCOUNT:table/TABLENAME \
  --s3-bucket BUCKET --s3-prefix PREFIX \
  --incremental-export-specification ExportFromTime=START_OF_DAY,ExportToTime=END_OF_DAY,ExportViewType=NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES \
  --export-type INCREMENTAL_EXPORT
```

You could use [EventBridge Scheduler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/what-is-scheduler.html) to run an incremental export every 24 hours.  Although it's possible for the scheduler to [target API commands directly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/managing-targets-universal.html), in your case I think the schedule would require a [Lambda target](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/managing-targets-templated.html).  The Lambda would calculate the current day's `ExportFromTime` and `ExportToTime` and call the export command.